# Why does Scikit-Learn's DecisionTreeClassifier return zero weighted features after removing zero weighted features and refitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree, feature-selection

Ive been trying to figure out why this is happening.  I'm fitting a `DecisionTreeClassifier` and the model determines that a few features are not informative for the prediction.  Fitting the same model with the same hyperparameters using all of the informative features (i.e., features that have a weight > 0), now I get other features that have zero weights that had non-zero weights before?

My questions:

- Is this behavior expected?
- If so, how can I use a `while` loop to remove features until none of the feature weights are zero?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
y = pd.Series({1: 'Negative', 2: 'Positive', 3: 'Positive', 4: 'Negative', 5: 'Positive', 6: 'Negative', 7: 'Negative', 8: 'Negative', 9: 'Negative', 10: 'Negative', 11: 'Negative', 12: 'Negative', 13: 'Negative', 14: 'Negative', 15: 'Negative', 16: 'Negative', 17: 'Negative', 18: 'Negative', 19: 'Negative', 20: 'Negative', 21: 'Negative', 22: 'Negative', 23: 'Negative', 24: 'Negative', 25: 'Negative', 26: 'Negative', 27: 'Negative', 28: 'Negative', 29: 'Negative', 30: 'Negative', 31: 'Negative', 32: 'Negative', 33: 'Negative', 34: 'Negative', 35: 'Negative', 36: 'Positive', 37: 'Negative', 38: 'Positive', 39: 'Positive', 40: 'Positive', 41: 'Positive', 42: 'Negative', 43: 'Negative', 44: 'Positive', 45: 'Positive', 46: 'Negative', 47: 'Negative', 48: 'Positive', 49: 'Positive', 50: 'Negative', 51: 'Negative', 52: 'Negative', 53: 'Positive', 54: 'Positive', 55: 'Positive', 56: 'Negative', 57: 'Positive', 58: 'Positive', 59: 'Positive', 60: 'Negative', 61: 'Negative', 62: 'Negative', 63: 'Positive', 64: 'Positive', 65: 'Positive', 66: 'Negative', 67: 'Positive', 68: 'Negative', 69: 'Negative', 70: 'Negative', 71: 'Positive', 72: 'Positive', 73: 'Negative', 74: 'Positive', 75: 'Positive', 76: 'Positive', 77: 'Positive', 78: 'Positive', 79: 'Positive', 80: 'Negative'})
X = pd.DataFrame({'ASV019': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 344, 5: 0, 6: 1468, 7: 669, 8: 646, 9: 1192, 10: 169, 11: 801, 12: 793, 13: 147, 14: 27, 15: 34, 16: 1324, 17: 196, 18: 181, 19: 955, 20: 144, 21: 460, 22: 1563, 23: 253, 24: 1590, 25: 429, 26: 973, 27: 523, 28: 901, 29: 766, 30: 417, 31: 726, 32: 955, 33: 630, 34: 580, 35: 1002, 36: 0, 37: 696, 38: 0, 39: 20, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 87, 47: 162, 48: 0, 49: 0, 50: 173, 51: 215, 52: 634, 53: 0, 54: 40, 55: 0, 56: 17, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 787, 61: 503, 62: 439, 63: 0, 64: 25, 65: 0, 66: 365, 67: 0, 68: 252, 69: 382, 70: 1694, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 21, 74: 0, 75: 3069, 76: 0, 77: 2, 78: 80, 79: 0, 80: 0}, 'ASV552': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 81, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 0, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 0, 47: 0, 48: 15, 49: 16, 50: 0, 51: 0, 52: 13, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 0, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 0, 64: 0, 65: 0, 66: 0, 67: 0, 68: 0, 69: 0, 70: 0, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 0, 74: 0, 75: 0, 76: 0, 77: 0, 78: 0, 79: 0, 80: 0}, 'ASV007': {1: 217, 2: 1673, 3: 4694, 4: 669, 5: 2734, 6: 388, 7: 210, 8: 213, 9: 568, 10: 329, 11: 703, 12: 677, 13: 776, 14: 505, 15: 987, 16: 400, 17: 334, 18: 133, 19: 0, 20: 405, 21: 475, 22: 740, 23: 766, 24: 364, 25: 705, 26: 1099, 27: 143, 28: 270, 29: 134, 30: 229, 31: 317, 32: 84, 33: 449, 34: 92, 35: 207, 36: 9288, 37: 461, 38: 135, 39: 342, 40: 464, 41: 1043, 42: 4693, 43: 2858, 44: 197, 45: 2083, 46: 223, 47: 822, 48: 1036, 49: 11656, 50: 0, 51: 348, 52: 1089, 53: 465, 54: 72, 55: 0, 56: 3885, 57: 2849, 58: 1000, 59: 4091, 60: 0, 61: 639, 62: 459, 63: 619, 64: 2563, 65: 919, 66: 1266, 67: 3038, 68: 622, 69: 521, 70: 296, 71: 10603, 72: 828, 73: 4849, 74: 5995, 75: 1252, 76: 3165, 77: 682, 78: 4219, 79: 3732, 80: 1603}, 'ASV135': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 700, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 0, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 0, 47: 0, 48: 0, 49: 0, 50: 0, 51: 92, 52: 767, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 0, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 0, 64: 0, 65: 0, 66: 0, 67: 0, 68: 0, 69: 408, 70: 0, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 0, 74: 0, 75: 0, 76: 0, 77: 0, 78: 0, 79: 0, 80: 0}, 'ASV122': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 1303, 6: 6, 7: 26, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 5, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 19, 26: 0, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 17, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 82, 39: 0, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 0, 47: 0, 48: 0, 49: 0, 50: 0, 51: 0, 52: 0, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 70, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 411, 61: 0, 62: 37, 63: 32, 64: 0, 65: 0, 66: 0, 67: 0, 68: 0, 69: 11, 70: 0, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 0, 74: 0, 75: 5, 76: 12, 77: 0, 78: 252, 79: 0, 80: 0}, 'ASV952': {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 9, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 0, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 6, 40: 0, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 0, 44: 0, 45: 0, 46: 0, 47: 0, 48: 0, 49: 0, 50: 0, 51: 0, 52: 0, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 0, 58: 0, 59: 0, 60: 0, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 5, 64: 0, 65: 0, 66: 7, 67: 0, 68: 0, 69: 0, 70: 0, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 0, 74: 0, 75: 0, 76: 0, 77: 0, 78: 0, 79: 0, 80: 0}, 'ASV156': {1: 0, 2: 26, 3: 0, 4: 3, 5: 72, 6: 2, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0, 22: 0, 23: 0, 24: 0, 25: 0, 26: 12, 27: 0, 28: 0, 29: 0, 30: 0, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 0, 34: 0, 35: 0, 36: 0, 37: 0, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 22, 41: 0, 42: 0, 43: 2, 44: 4, 45: 0, 46: 9, 47: 0, 48: 11, 49: 15, 50: 0, 51: 0, 52: 0, 53: 0, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 0, 57: 0, 58: 35, 59: 0, 60: 0, 61: 0, 62: 0, 63: 0, 64: 0, 65: 7, 66: 8, 67: 88, 68: 67, 69: 15, 70: 0, 71: 0, 72: 0, 73: 76, 74: 1069, 75: 14, 76: 4, 77: 49, 78: 3, 79: 5, 80: 24}, 'ASV062': {1: 199, 2: 209, 3: 0, 4: 315, 5: 0, 6: 49, 7: 63, 8: 25, 9: 29, 10: 22, 11: 24, 12: 141, 13: 0, 14: 62, 15: 49, 16: 0, 17: 288, 18: 274, 19: 0, 20: 59, 21: 134, 22: 10, 23: 147, 24: 22, 25: 101, 26: 78, 27: 0, 28: 25, 29: 47, 30: 105, 31: 0, 32: 0, 33: 74, 34: 53, 35: 110, 36: 0, 37: 8, 38: 0, 39: 0, 40: 6, 41: 0, 42: 226, 43: 21, 44: 0, 45: 373, 46: 98, 47: 126, 48: 5, 49: 8, 50: 186, 51: 93, 52: 35, 53: 21, 54: 0, 55: 0, 56: 720, 57: 3, 58: 220, 59: 0, 60: 230, 61: 41, 62: 118, 63: 0, 64: 0, 65: 0, 66: 151, 67: 0, 68: 186, 69: 225, 70: 6, 71: 22, 72: 13, 73: 97, 74: 0, 75: 2, 76: 5, 77: 134, 78: 0, 79: 0, 80: 84}})

# Model
params = {'ccp_alpha': 0.0, 'class_weight': None, 'criterion': 'entropy', 'max_depth': None, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_leaf_nodes': None, 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0, 'min_samples_leaf': 1, 'min_samples_split': 2, 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0, 'random_state': 0, 'splitter': 'best'}
estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(**params)

# Fit model
estimator.fit(X,y)
estimator.feature_importances_
# array([0.68181101, 0.        , 0.10029598, 0.        , 0.03051763,
#        0.        , 0.        , 0.18737538])

# Mask zero weighted features and refit
X_1 = X.loc[:,estimator.feature_importances_ > 0]
estimator.fit(X_1,y)
estimator.feature_importances_
# array([0.51290959, 0.11922515, 0.        , 0.36786526])

# One more time
X_2 = X_1.loc[:,estimator.feature_importances_ > 0]
estimator.fit(X_2,y)
estimator.feature_importances_
# array([0.38116661, 0.32724164, 0.29159175])
```

Comment: A few points. (1) DT feature importance depends on which features appear in the tree, and trees can be sensitive to data splits. (2) For nonlinear models some features are more informative when paired [bear with me for a silly example], if we're predicting 'body mass index': 'height' *and* 'weight' are more informative than either feature individually. (3) Do you have an application that [recursive feature elimination](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV) cannot handle?

Comment: 1 & 2) This makes perfect sense and is what I was suspecting but just wanted to have a little more input before I move on.  3) I'm working on a custom version that has a few extra bells and whistles.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this "isn't unexpected" (but wouldn't go so far as to say it's "expected").

With `max_features!=1.0`, the number of informative features chosen depends on the number of features available. After pruning out some (relatively-)uninformative features, your `log2(n_features)` changes, and so one of those remaining never out-competes the final three features for a split.

Even if you don't perform feature subsetting, there's a (rarer) possibility of this phenomenon based on the random state affecting ordering features differently when they have different numbers.